# Ubuntu 12.04 138a:0017 driver for fingerprint reader is missing

Tags: 12.04, drivers, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

In my laptop I have a fingerprint reader, and either `fprint` and `fingerprint-gui` cant detect it. I have ubuntu 12.04 lts
The fingerprint id is as follows:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc.
```

And one more question, Ubuntu has certified all of the components of my laptop, like for example, my wifi card (which currently has no driver), and the fingerprint sensor.
One example for the certification is this one at [www.ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201307-13930/components/). (which says that the fingerprint reader is supported)

I know that it was supported for a `oem` install by the manufacturer, however, I really would like to have the drivers.

Wifi card model : realtek 8192ee

How can I resolve this ?

```
$~ sudo rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

The lsusb fingerprint reader related output (since it isn't on pci):

```
$~ lsusb -vv #just showing the fingerprint related output otherwise i think it would be too long.
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass        17 
  bDeviceProtocol       255 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x138a Validity Sensors, Inc.
  idProduct          0x0017 
  bcdDevice            0.78
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 1 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           46
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               4
```

The full lspci -vv output:

```
$~ lspci -vv
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 220e
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0
Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x8 Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
Memory behind bridge: f0000000-f0ffffff
Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000d1ffffff
Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 220f
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 46
Region 0: Memory at f1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Region 2: Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Region 4: I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915_hsw

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 220e
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 43
Region 0: Memory at f1630000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 220e
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 48
Region 0: Memory at f1620000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 220e
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx+
Latency: 0
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
Region 0: Memory at f1639000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
Capabilities: <access denied>

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 220e
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 42
Region 0: Memory at f1600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
Region 1: Memory at f163f000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Region 2: I/O ports at 5080 [size=32]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
Kernel modules: e1000e

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 220e
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
Region 0: Memory at f163e000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 220e
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 47
Region 0: Memory at f1634000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
Memory behind bridge: f1500000-f15fffff
Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
Memory behind bridge: f1400000-f14fffff
Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 220e
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 23
Region 0: Memory at f163d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 220e
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 220e
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0
Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 45
Region 0: I/O ports at 50a8 [size=8]
Region 1: I/O ports at 50b4 [size=4]
Region 2: I/O ports at 50a0 [size=8]
Region 3: I/O ports at 50b0 [size=4]
Region 4: I/O ports at 5060 [size=32]
Region 5: Memory at f163c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 220e
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 10
Region 0: Memory at f1638000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
Region 4: I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
Kernel modules: i2c-i801

02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 730M] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
Region 0: Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Region 1: Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Region 3: Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
Region 5: I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidiafb

03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5227 (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 220e
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 44
Region 0: Memory at f1500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
Kernel modules: rtsx_pci

04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 818b
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 001b
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 10
Region 0: I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
Region 2: Memory at f1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: rtl8192ee
```

Comment: Run `lspci -vv`, and look for the bit after `Kernel driver in use: ` for those particular things. What is your wifi card's make and model, and what is your fingerprint reader's model? Also, what does `sudo rfkill list` produce?

Comment: I couldn't find the validity sensors in the lspci, i think it's connected by usb.

Comment: And i didn't found the fingerprint reader model. how can i find it ? (i already have it's id)

Comment: `lshw` is another option. Validity Sensors website says *If you have a notebook computer with a Validtiy fingerprint sensor and are looking for software drivers, please refer to your PC manufacturer for the latest software and driver packages that are compatible with your machine.* Lenovo have [this](http://support.lenovo.com/en_GB/downloads/default.page?selector=expand), but you will have to find them yourself due to model number etc.

Comment: It looks like fprint doesn't support `138a:0017` yet, though someone appears to have opened a [pull request on the project](https://github.com/ars3niy/fprint_vfs5011/pull/8) that adds that identifier.  I haven't built and tested fprint with this patch (yet?), but if it works, hopefully it'll be merged soon…